# How can i switch from one drive to another drive using groovy

Tags: groovy, cmd

I want to change directory to d:\apps\documents.Then create a folder 'money' in that then again change to d:\apps\documents\money.i am trying below code but unable to get the  desired output.Any help would be great as i am a beginner.

```
def proc= ['cmd', '/c','cd','/d','d:\\apps\\documents']

Process process=proc.execute(null, new File('C:/'));
process.waitForOrKill( 2000 )
println process.text

def proc1= ['cmd','/c','mkdir','money']
Process process1=proc1.execute(null, new File('C:/'))
process1.waitForOrKill( 2000 )
println process1.text
```

This is creating  a folder money in c drive but i want it to create it in d:\apps\documents

```
def proc2= ['cmd', '/c','cd','/d','d:\\apps\\documents\\money']
Process process2=proc2.execute(null, new File('C:/'));
process2.waitForOrKill( 2000 )
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of context?  Is this a commandline tool you're writing?  Why not just use BAT commands?

Comment: i have to execute these cmd commands on groovy console.you mean to use bat script right?

Comment: `new File('D:\\apps\\documents\\money').mkdir();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't modify your current working directory of your current Groovy process, this is not possible. What you do is, you open a new process in `C:`, there you change the working directory. Then you again open a new process again in `C:` and create the directory there.

I guess your code is not your real use-case, because using native command execution for creating a directory is non-sense if you are in Groovy where you can do it much easier and in a portable way, so I'm not gonna suggest a concrete solution as the use-case is not clear.